# Tags column to dummy columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Imagine a very simple csv file that looks like this:

```
output,input,tags
0,0,sunday-hot
1,3,sunday
5,1,hot-random
```

where the tags column is made up of a series of keywords all separated by "-".
What I would like is to turn it into a dataset that looks like this:

```
output,input,sunday,hot,random
0,0,T,T,F
1,3,T,F,F
5,1,F,T,T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with *dplyr/tidyr*. Use `separate_rows()` to separate the pasted *tags* column to a normal column which contains one value in each cell; Create a *value* column that contains all *TRUE* to spread on; Fill missing values with *FALSE*:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

df %>% separate_rows(tags) %>% 
       mutate(val = TRUE) %>% 
       spread(tags, val, fill = FALSE)

#  output input   hot random sunday
#1      0     0  TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
#2      1     3 FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
#3      5     1  TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with a one-liner using `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df1[-3], mtabulate(strsplit(df1$tags, "-"))!=0)
#   output input   hot random sunday
#1      0     0  TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
#2      1     3 FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
#3      5     1  TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
```

NOTE: If the "tags" column is `factor` class, wrap it with `as.character` as `strsplit` takes only `character` class as input

Comment: Didn't know about this library. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

the way you want to store the data is not efficient at all because you will create an **insane** amount of columns whose values will be missing most of the time.

Instead, have a look at https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext and the `unnest_tokens` function.